# Welchen Fall oder welche Präposition verlangt »untersuchen«?

Tags: verb, preposition

Verlangt *untersuchen* eine Präposition und falls nicht, welchen Fall verlangt es?

Comment: Kannst Du erläutern, wieso ein Wörterbuch diese Frage nicht zufriedenstellend beantworten konnte?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Das Verb „untersuchen“ wird meistens entweder ohne Präposition mit dem Akkusativ *(etwas untersuchen; jemanden untersuchen)*

> die klimatischen Bedingungen untersuchen
>   die Beschaffenheit des Bodens untersuchen
>   die gesellschaftlichen Verhältnisse untersuchen
>   ein Thema untersuchen
>   ein Problem untersuchen
>   etwas chemisch untersuchen
>   einen Patienten nur flüchtig untersuchen
>   einen Patienten oberflächlich untersuchen
>   sich ärztlich untersuchen lassen
>   den Hals untersuchen
>   die Wunde untersuchen
>   die Lunge untersuchen
>   den ganzen Körper sorgfältig untersuchen
>   einen Unfall untersuchen
>   den Tathergang untersuchen
>   einen Fall gerichtlich untersuchen
>   jemanden untersuchen
>   jemandes Gepäck untersuchen

oder zusammen mit der Präposition „auf“ *(etwas auf etwas untersuchen; jemanden auf etwas untersuchen)* verwendet.

> das Blut auf Zucker untersuchen
>   den Wein auf seine Reinheit untersuchen
>   jemanden auf seinen psychischen Zustand [hin] untersuchen
>   die Fahrzeuge auf Waffen untersuchen
>   das Auto auf seine Fahrtüchtigkeit [hin] untersuchen

Es sind allerdings auch andere Präpositionen und entsprechende Fälle möglich:

> etwas unter dem Mikroskop untersuchen
>   einen Patienten an der Lunge untersuchen
>   die Fahrzeuge nach Waffen untersuchen

(Beispiele aus: *Duden Band 2 – Das Stilwörterbuch,* 9. Auflage, 2010)

Answer (score 2):

No, just an accusative object (as a rule).

> Der Chemiker untersucht die Probe auf Spuren von Schwefel.
>
> Der Arzt hat die Wunde vor der Behandlung untersucht.
>
> Der Fall wurde lange und genau untersucht.